# JQuery carousel track looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble making the images inside the slider loop around. I want track to loop around from either sides after they are hidden. here is the
the jsfiddle for what I have now. http://jsfiddle.net/V2x6s/3/

Here's Javascript

```js
setInterval(function() {
    var left1 = parseInt($('#track1').css('left')),
        left2 = parseInt($('#track2').css('left')),
        left3 = parseInt($('#track3').css('left'));
    
    if ($('#left1').is(":hover")) {
        $('#track1').css('left', left1+2);
    }
    else if ($('#left2').is(":hover")) {
        $('#track2').css('left', left2+2);
    }
    else if ($('#left3').is(":hover")) {
        $('#track3').css('left', left3+2);
    }
    else if ($('#right1').is(":hover")) {
        $('#track1').css('left', left1-2);
    }
    else if ($('#right2').is(":hover")) {
        $('#track2').css('left', left2-2);
    }
    else if ($('#right3').is(":hover")) {
        $('#track3').css('left', left3-2);
    }
    
}, 10);
```

```css
.slider {
    position: relative;
    
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    
    overflow: hidden;
}
.track {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;

    width: 2000px;
}
.book {
    float: left;
    
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.book:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.book:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.book:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #ffaa00;
}
.book:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
.book:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
.book:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
.book:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: #aa00ff;
}
.book:nth-child(7) {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
}
.left, .right {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
    top: 57px;
    
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}
.left {
    left: 0;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div id="left1" class="left">&lt;</div>
    <div id="right1" class="right">&gt;</div>
    <div class="track" id="track1">
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
    <div id="left2" class="left">&lt;</div>
    <div id="right2" class="right">&gt;</div>
    <div class="track" id="track2">
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
    <div id="left3" class="left">&lt;</div>
    <div id="right3" class="right">&gt;</div>
    <div class="track" id="track3">
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c0utx50d/)**

this is how I would do... I would calculate the window width and the elements width, and use them...

```
// $('#track1').parent().width() - gives window width
// $('#track1 .book').length * ($('#track1 .book').width() + 5) - gives combined elements width
    if ($('#left1').is(":hover")) {
        var move = left1+20;
        if(move > $('#track1').parent().width())
            move = $('#track1 .book').length * ($('#track1 .book').width() + 5) * -1;
        $('#track1').css('left', move);
        //console.log(left1+20, tmp,$('#track1').parent().width() );
    }
    else if ($('#right1').is(":hover")) {
        var move = left1-20;
        if(move < $('#track1 .book').length * ($('#track1 .book').width() + 5) * -1 )
            move = $('#track1').parent().width();
        $('#track1').css('left', move);
        //console.log(left1-20, tmp,$('#track1').parent().width() );
    }
```

you can modify the others similarly, also using `setInterval` to moniter is a bad idea if you ask me.

#### Edit:

I would do it like : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c0utx50d/1/)

```
$('.left').hover(function(){
    moveLeft($(this));
});

$('.right').hover(function(){
    moveRight($(this));
});
function moveLeft(ele){
    if(ele.is(":hover")){
        var track = ele.next().next(),
            move = parseInt(track.css('left'))+10,
            books = track.find('.book'),
            wid = (books.length * (books.width()+5)) * -1;
        if(move > track.parent().width())   move = wid;
        track.css('left', move);
        setTimeout(moveLeft.bind(null, ele), 50); // change 20 to whatever number you like
    }  
}    
function moveRight(ele){
    if(ele.is(":hover")){
        var track = ele.next(),
            move = parseInt(track.css('left'))-10,
            books = track.find('.book'),
            wid = (books.length * (books.width()+5)) * -1;
        if(move < wid )   move = track.parent().width();
        track.css('left', move);
        setTimeout(moveRight.bind(null, ele), 50); // change 20 to whatever number you like
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help... also what would you suggest other than the setInterval function

Comment: @solidStateV.s. updated answer, check now, also if the answer is satisfactory, select accept.

Comment: is there a way to have the carousel show the books on the left side before they are hidden on the right? so the track won't look blank after the row of books are hidden.